# Reducing VPC Endpoint costs - deploying an image to Amazon ECS with CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr

I have a basic understanding of AWS architecture, however I need a way to reduce current costs. My current pipeline is as follows:

1. Source react app code from Github
2. Use CodeBuild to build a docker container and push it to the ECR.
3. Deploy the container into ECS Fargate Cluster

For security reasons, I do not want my ECS service to auto-assign a public IP. Instead I have been using VPC endpoints within the same subnets that the cluster operates in, for the following services:

- com.amazonaws.eu-west-2.ecr.dkr (Interface)
- com.amazonaws.eu-west-2.ecr.api (Interface)
- com.amazonaws.eu-west-2.logs (Interface)
- com.amazonaws.eu-west-2.secretsmanager (Interface)
- com.amazonaws.eu-west-2.s3 (Gateway)

The downside to this is now the majority of my AWS bill is taken up by having VPC endpoints stood up. The two options I thought of are:

- Put a CloudFormation step in CodePipeline to stand up the VPC endpoints before ECS deployment, and delete manually after deployment
- Create a Lambda function step in CodePipeline to stand up the VPC endpoints before deployment, and another Lambda step to delete them afterwards.

Are either of these "best practice" or is there another way I could automatically create/delete these endpoints when required?
Any further info required let me know.

Comment: Neither of those options would be considered "best practice", since any automated replacement of your service in the event of one of your containers crashing, or due to a problem with the underlying hardware, would now fail due to the endpoints being missing.

Comment: You could consider running a cluster on EC2, and deploying the image on the EC2 instance?

Comment: How would your solutions help if the minimum billing period is one hour? https://aws.amazon.com/privatelink/pricing/#Interface_Endpoint_pricing